# Как попасть в else первого if?

Tags: python, if

Если первую проверку прошел, а вторую нет, мне нужно попасть в else первого if

```
a = 1
b = 3
def f(x, y):
    if x != 0:      # 1я проверка
        if y == 1:  # 2я проверка
            print('waw')
    else:
        print('over')

f(a,b) # ожидаемый результат 'over', но функция ничего не выводит
```

(условие and условие) - не подходит. нужна двойная поэтапная проверка, и если вторую проверку не прошел нужно выполнить код в else первого if. Так наверное нельзя сделать?

Comment: А если не And, а Or проверку? if x != 0 or y == 1: ... else: ...? По идее двойная проверка отдельная нужна именно если нужно после второй попасть в else ВТОРОЙ проверки, а от первой в первый и они разные, хм... Вот тут с примерами как писать: https://realpython.com/python-or-operator/#if-statements

Comment: К сожалению, or не подходит.

Comment: Как раз таки нужно использовать and: `if x != 0 and y == 1: ... else: ...`. Или что должно происходить, если первую проверку не прошел?

Comment: ^ ага, сообразил, туплю, однако. Реально надо делать либо and, либо all как в ответе рекомендуют.

Comment: А зачем таки именно поэтапно, если у тебя всего 2 варианта исхода? Либо оба да, и тогда да, либо хотя бы один нет и тогда нет?

Answer (score 3):

Проверки можно объединить через функцию [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), когда требуется выполнение всех включенных в нее условий.

```
def f(x, y):
    if all([x != 0, y == 1]):      # 1я проверка
        print('waw')
    else:
        print('over')

a = 1
b = 3
f(a,b)  # over
```

Comment: Уелкам) Советую также посмотреть проверку типа `any()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any `all()` и `any()` несколько удобнее группировки через `and` и `or`.

Comment: В чем это удобнее группировки через and/or?

Comment: Тем, что не надо через `and`/`or` перечислять. Сокращение кода, что удобно, когда проверок много. Можно динамический список условий делать. Редко, но иногда бывает нужно.

Comment: все же не подходит. Это получается как c and. А мне нужно чтобы  если первую проверку не проходит, вторую проверку не трогало. Но если прошло первую проверку и не проходит вторую проверку, запустился else верхнего if

Comment: Просто уже прям любопытно стало. Оно тебе зачем такое извращение? И чем тебя таки `реально` не устраивает And? И да, таки хотелось бы реальный пример применения такого бдсма где не работает AND... В смысле 2 проверку не трогало? У тебя там функции которые чего то изменяют, что ли?

Comment: Пример можно? В этом случае, если у Вас не проходит любая из двух проверок, то получаем `False` и уходим на первый `else`. Если первая проверка не пройдет, то и вторую не тронет)

Comment: спасибо. я попробую позже подготовить реальный пример .

Comment: И да... Да запихни ты все что у тебя в else в отдельную функцию. И на нее дважды сошлись. И сделай тупо два `else: do_else_things(arg1, arg2, arg3, etc.)`, только все что туда нужно передавать проверь.

Comment: Пример очень нужен. Пока не вижу смысла отказываться от `all()` или `and`. Два последовательных `if` без внутреннего `else` выполняются именно в этом ключе.

Comment: Для проверки двух-трех условий использовать all - это какой-то оверкилл. В ответе вместо одного оператора из 3 букв написать функцию из 3 букв, 2 пары скобочек и еще запятую - так себе сокращение кода.

Comment: Зато нету разделения лишним оператором, а все условия идут через запятую. И условий иногда бывает больше двух-трех. Ну и вариант с `and` уже указан выше в комментариях к посту.

Comment: По мне вариант `a == b and c == d and f == e` менее читабельный, чем `all([a == b, c == d, f == e])`

Comment: 1 - комментарий не ответ, никто не мешает указать этот вариант в своем ответе, это же не какое-то ноу-хау, а просто обычная конструкция языка. 2 - вариант `if all([x != 0, y == 1])` менее читабельный, чем  `if x != 0 and y == 1`. По поводу `a == b and c == d and f == e` уже надо смотреть конкретно, но в любом случае я считаю, что лучше использовать обычную конструкцию, чем какие-то выверты (следуя правилу наименьшего удивления). 3 - используйте обращение через @, у вас в большей части комментариев непонятно к кому вы обращаетесь.